# Nested queries SQL?

Tags: html, sql, nest

I have a problem to output my records in desired order. My table looks like this:

```
04/15/2016     8:00  AM - 8:20  AM
04/15/2016     8:20  AM - 8:40  AM
04/15/2016     8:40  AM - 9:00  AM
04/15/2016     9:00  AM - 9:20  AM
04/15/2016     9:20  AM - 9:40  AM
04/15/2016     9:40  AM - 10:00  AM
04/15/2016     10:00  AM - 10:20  AM
04/15/2016     10:20  AM - 10:40  AM
04/15/2016     10:40  AM - 11:00  AM
04/15/2016     11:00  AM - 11:20  AM
04/22/2016     7:30  AM - 7:50  AM
04/22/2016     7:50  AM - 8:10  AM
04/22/2016     8:10  AM - 8:30  AM
04/22/2016     8:30  AM - 8:50  AM
04/22/2016     8:50  AM - 9:10  AM
04/22/2016     9:10  AM - 9:30  AM
04/22/2016     9:30  AM - 9:50  AM
04/22/2016     9:50  AM - 10:10  AM
04/22/2016     10:10  AM - 10:30  AM
```

As you can see above I have date value in each row. My desired output will be to have only one date value and all time slots for that date. That can be on the side using rowspan or in my th tag using colspan. To clarify I can not use javascript and create dynamic table in this case. I tried and that did not work for some other reasons. I have to output my values from SQL Query to HTML table. So I was wondering what would be the best way to do this? Should I use nested queries and how that would look like or there is some other way to do this?

Here is query that gives me single dates:

```
Select Distinct to_char(s.PTC_DATE,'mm/dd/yyyy')
From EVENTS e
Left Outer Join EVENT_SLOTS s
On e.ID = s.EVENT_ID
Where e.PTC_FLAG = '1'
And e.ID = '3295'   
Order by to_char(s.PTC_DATE,'mm/dd/yyyy')
```

Output:

```
10/19/2016
10/20/2016
```

And here is another query that gives me time slots:

```
Select s.SLOT_LABEL
From EVENTS e
Left Outer Join EVENT_SLOTS s
On e.ID = s.EVENT_ID
Where e.PTC_FLAG = '1'
And e.ID = '2519'
Order by s.PTC_DATE, s.DISPLAY_ORDER
```

Output:

```
8:00  AM - 8:20  AM
8:20  AM - 8:40  AM
8:40  AM - 9:00  AM
9:00  AM - 9:20  AM
9:20  AM - 9:40  AM
9:40  AM - 10:00  AM
10:00  AM - 10:20  AM
10:20  AM - 10:40  AM
10:40  AM - 11:00  AM
11:00  AM - 11:20  AM
7:30  AM - 7:50  AM
7:50  AM - 8:10  AM
8:10  AM - 8:30  AM
8:30  AM - 8:50  AM
8:50  AM - 9:10  AM
9:10  AM - 9:30  AM
9:30  AM - 9:50  AM
9:50  AM - 10:10  AM
10:10  AM - 10:30  AM
```

How I can nest these two queries and output records in separate table for each date? If anyone can help with this please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select s.SLOT_LABEL
From EVENTS e
Left Outer Join EVENT_SLOTS s
On e.ID = s.EVENT_ID
Where e.PTC_FLAG = '1'
And e.ID = '2519'
AND e.PTD_DATE = [DateVariable] --***
Order by s.PTC_DATE, s.DISPLAY_ORDER
```

***This is what you need to only pull the time slots for the selected date.  You can loop through your first result set (all of the dates), and pass each one into this query.